# Using Md-icon, I can't display the custom svg

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I can display svg formatted icons from default angular material design.

But not to own made custom icon, and use it like:

```
<md-icon aria-label="..." md-svg-icon="img/deal-review-ui/svg/custom.svg"></md-icon>
```

***Why?***

Here is the custom svg:

```
 <svg width="404" height="404" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="406" width="406" y="-1" x="-1"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <ellipse stroke="#293414" ry="200" rx="200" id="svg_1" cy="202" cx="202" stroke-width="0" fill="#bbd7bc"/>
  <text stroke="#293414" transform="rotate(0.031844597309827805 198.77488708493877,179.41534423829142) matrix(15.453970455039329,0,0,13.162668315715782,-2099.761752733419,-1738.4265600781666) " xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_5" y="154.038217" x="140.749918" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">A</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What you have done does work - https://plnkr.co/edit/BeqDGCHAAasbvgYsIGH0?p=preview. You can see a part of the svg when the `md-icon` width is set to 400px. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about svg to help you any further.

Comment: yes, you are correct. All I need to do is to minimize the svg.

Comment: Carlos, if you arrived at a solution that's not mentioned below, please provide it as an answer and accept it to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `md-svg-src` instead of `md-svg-icon`

`md-svg-src`: String URL (or expression) used to load, cache, and display an external SVG. You can see more [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon).